# Checking radio button if div gets made visible

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following function which is meant to check the radio button button if the div gets made visible.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  if ($('.paymentOption').not(':hidden')) {
    $("#showBank").prop("checked",false);
  } else {
     $("#showBank").prop("checked",true);
  }
});
```

At the moment the following div isn't being made visible and i'm unsure why as i get no errors.

```html
<div class="ccGateway">
  <h4>
    <input id="showBank" onclick="javascript:checkoutSwitch(true);controlDivPayment('[id]');" name="payment"
           type="radio" value="online-[id]"/>
    [payment_description]</h4>
  <p><img border="0" src="assets/images/banners/credit_cards.jpg" width="189" height="38"></p>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div id="divPaymentOption[id]" name="divPaymentOption" class="paymentOption" style="display:none;">
    <div class="desc-message">[payment_description_message]</div>
    <div class="ccgField">
      <label for="creditcardnumber">[CustomerInfo_creditcardnumber]</label>
      <input type="text" onchange="clearContent(this);" name="ff[id]_ocardno" size="30" class="txtBoxStyle"/>
      <img src="assets/templates/common/images/error2.gif" width="12" height="12" alt=""/>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your syntax is wrong: `$(document).ready(function ()){ //...` should be `$(document).ready(function (){ //...` You are closing one of the brackets too early.

Comment: your id is `divPaymentOption[id]` but your selector doesn't have the square brackets, as well as the above error

Comment: Updated my question. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see if this helps you? Run Snippet

(I included a button to unmark the radio button and then it check the display again after 2 seconds, just to demonstrate it working)

Any Question, just ask me in the comments :D

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

CheckIfdisplayNone = function(){
    if ($("[name='divPaymentOption']").css('display') != 'none'){
        $("#showBank").prop("checked",false);
    } else{
        $("#showBank").prop("checked",true);
    }
  }
  
  UnmarkRadio = function(){
    $("#showBank").prop("checked",false);
    setTimeout(function(){CheckIfdisplayNone();}, 2000);
  }
  
  CheckIfdisplayNone();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="showBank" onclick="javascript:checkoutSwitch(true);controlDivPayment('[id]');" name="payment" type="radio" value="online-[id]"/>
<h4>[payment_description]</h4>
<p><img border="0" src="assets/images/banners/credit_cards.jpg" width="189" height="38"></p>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="divPaymentOption[id]" name="divPaymentOption" style="display:none;">
    <div class="desc-message">[payment_description_message]</div>
    <div class="ccgField">
        <label for="creditcardnumber">[CustomerInfo_creditcardnumber]</label>
        <input type="text" onchange="clearContent(this);" name="ff[id]_ocardno" size="30" class="txtBoxStyle"/>
        <img src="assets/templates/common/images/error2.gif" width="12" height="12" alt=""/>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>    
</div>
<button onClick='UnmarkRadio();' value="uncheck">uncheck</button>
```